# Is there any algorithm available for this kind of optimization problem

Tags: matrices, optimization, integer-programming

My optimization problem is to design a $n*m$ matrix consisting of only $0$ and $1$ as elements, such that the sum of each column is not less than a number given as the constraints. The constraints is given in a form of an integer vector with length of m (so, $m$ is known).

My objective is to work out the matrix with the minimal $n$ (i.e. number of rows).

To construct a new row in the matrix, a coding schema (as shown below, it is a pattern of $0$, $1$ digits with repetition on the pattern, e.g. assuming a pattern of $[1,1,0]$ and repeat it twice to $[1,1,0,1,1,0]$) was required to satisfy.

I will give a simple example below:

Assuming the constraint vector for the sum of each column is 
$$
[3,4,5,2,2,5,3,4,2,5]
$$

The row allowed in the matrix is in a form like

$$
[1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0]
$$

which is consisting of only $0$ and $1$ as aforementioned.

Besides, each row is a $10$-element vector with a fixed pattern repeated twice in the row. The pattern is $[1,1,0,0,0]$.

To begin with the construction of the $n*10$ matrix, I add $3$ rows to meet the first number in constraint vector, i.e.$3$.

$$
[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0] \\
[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0] \\
[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]
$$

So, in current matrix, the sum of first column equals to $3$. Also $n = 3$ at this stage.

Then I move to the next number in constraint vector. It is $4$. That means I need to add one extra row in that pattern.

$$
[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0] \\
[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0] \\
[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0] \\
[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
$$

The new row takes a form of $[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]$. This is from my transforming the standard form $[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]$ by moving it rightward one step and looped the last element $0$ to the head of the new row. This process just makes sure the second column and all its leftward columns meet the sum of constraints.

Then just execute this process $10$ times until all elements in constraint vector were considered and met.

As a result, I will get the derived $n*10$ matrix. And the n is the solution I found.

In my real problem, the problem size is larger than this where $m=336$, also the coding schema is much more complex than just repeating $[1,1,0,0,0]$. So the searching space of the optimal solution is much larger than the case above. I have no idea how to program an algorithm to search the optimal solution. What kind of programming problem it belongs to and any existing algorithm can help? Cheers

Comment: Can you be more specific on this "coding schema"? That is a key part of this problem.

Comment: @Math1000 I have added more explanation on the coding schema. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enumerate the allowed row patterns, and let $x_i$ be the number of rows in pattern $i$ you use.  Then you have an integer linear programming problem:

Minimize $\sum_i x_i$

subject to
$$
\sum_i a_{ij} x_i \ge b_j \ \text{for}\ 1 \le j \le m$$
$x_i$ integers $\ge 0$

where $a_{ij}$ is the $j$'th element in pattern $i$ and $b_j$ is the minimum required sum for column $j$.

Comment: While this is correct, it can easily be intractable for large instances. Column generation may be a good approach if e.g. the number of feasible rows grows exponentially with $m$.